# Passport control within Schengen area

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, germany, sweden

I'm latin-american, don't need visa to enter (90/180 applies). I have been living in Sweden for two years with a residence permit during which I finished a master and right know I am applying to extend my permit for doctoral studies (since September). It is taking months due to the refugee crisis and by now I might be considered overstayer or something.

The point is that I have no visa right now because is still in process, further, due to bureaucratic reasons, I am asked to leave Sweden until is fully approved.

They ask me literally just to be out of Sweden so it can be approved. The migration official told me that I can go to the Swedish embassy in Berlin and send him my flight tickets which I will do. But I´m kind of panicking that I will have a problem since I have no visa and my passport shows that I entered Schengen in 2013.

I´m just going Stockholm-Berlin and back, and I have all my papers with me, including proof that my visa in Sweden is in process as well as the offer of employment. Do you think I will face some problem? especially with the current situation? Are they checking Schengen flights in Germany/Berlin?

Comment: When exactly did your residence permit expire? You have another 90 days from that date. But are you sure going to Berlin will be enough? It sounds a bit odd to me.

Comment: I flew from AMS to CGN on Monday, and they weren't checking.

Comment: It expired end of August and I applied beggining of September, it was not in my control since my supervisor and the university notified in September that I got the position. Effectively, I assume I have the 90 days and I guess they know it too beacuse I wasn´t requested to leave until now. The officer at migrationsverket in charge of my case gave me that option. Might not be the commonest thing but I pushed a bit to not travel so far since I cannot afford it right now, my salary comes with my PhD :S